# Code block only runs one time inside OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, codeblocks

```
lstviewBlockedVenues.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> obj, View arg1, int pos,
                long arg3) {


            Data.currVenueInfo = (VenueInfo) obj.getItemAtPosition(pos);
            String venueList = "";

            if(swipeDetector.swipeDetected())
            {

                try {
                    Button btnBlock = (Button) arg1.findViewById(R.id.btnBlockVen); 
                    Toasts.pop(getApplicationContext(), "Swiped");
                    System.out.println(btnBlock.getVisibility());

                        if(btnBlock.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE)
                        {
                            btnBlock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            btnBlock.setVisibility(View.GONE);                                                                          
                        }

                    System.out.println("Inside swipe");
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
        }
    });
```

In above code I am trying to show a button on a single row when user swipes the row. Initially button's visibility is gone. When I swipe on any row first time, it works perfect and the button one that row becomes visible. But if I swipe that same row again then the button should be gone as per the code I have written, but when I next time swipe the row, swipe event is detected but the code doesn't executes :(. but If I remove the lines `btnBlock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); and btnBlock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` then the toast msg and logcat msg is shown. I have no idea why its not working second time.

Thanks

Comment: fixed it, just changed the button Focusable to false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change that button's focusable to FALSE, as its not allowing the listview row to have the focus.